# Using mathspec’s \setallmainfonts with Russian in polyglossia causes hang during compilation

Tags: xetex, languages, polyglossia, mathspec

I’ve just run into a problem with the combination of `mathspec`’s `\setallmainfonts` command and `polyglossia` with language set to Russian. I’m using MiKTeX 2.9 and compiling with XeLaTeX and when I use these two together, compilation just hangs and doesn’t complete.

I’ve found that there’s a difference in the log file between when Russian and other languages are loaded. In the case of Russian there is one more line where it loads something like babel shorthands which is not present while loading other languages. Maybe that might have something to do with the problem.

The hang occurs only when I actually use some math commands in the document, either between `$` or using `equation` enviroment.

This is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setallmainfonts[Mapping=tex-text, Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}

\begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
 f(x)=\sigma
 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I’m using `mathspec` and `\setallmainfonts` because I want to change the math font (`\setmathsfont` causes the hang as well). So removing them is not an option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You observation about shorthands is correct. Loading `mathspec` redefines `\sigma` to `"σ`, makes `"` active and `\let`s a certain control sequence to this character. Loading `polyglossia` with the `russian` option makes `"` active again and overwrites the previous definition of `"`. `mathspec` also sets up `"` to be active in math mode. However, using it in math mode invokes the unexpecting `polyglossia` definition of `"`, which enters an infinite loop.

Simply swapping the two packages doesn't work because of `fontspec` option clash. What we can do is restore the `mathspec`'s meaning of `"` after `russian` has been loaded. It has to be done `\AtBeginDocument`, because `polyglossia` fiddles with `"` at that time, too.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts[Mapping=tex-text, Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
  \catcode`\"=\active
  \AtBeginDocument{\let"=\eu@active@quote}
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    f(x)=\sigma
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

In my opinion, both packages are at fault: they changes catcodes and definitions of active characters without explicit user's request.

EDIT: Polyglossia bug reported as [issue #28](https://github.com/fc7/polyglossia/issues/28).

Comment: Babel and Polyglossia at least declare in their documentation the activation of the characters, while mathspec uses `"` as math active without telling the user. There is, however a bug in Polyglossia, since the character is activated also without specifying that shorthands are enabled.

Comment: The link (bug report issue #28) is no longer valid. (Unfortunately, I don’t know what a valid version of said link would look like.)

Answer (score 1):

try this setting:

```
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Linux Libertine O}
```

Use any other math font, if Latin Modern Math is not available

Comment: One thing is that as far as I know you must specify (Digits, Latin, Greek) when using \setmathfont, then it might work. Nevertheless, I wouldn’t like to change the font. I want to use Linux Libertine for math. It works in other languages than Russian so I hope I should be able to make it work with Russian too.

Comment: Libertine has no math!

Comment: As you can read in the mathspec documentation, it can change only the font used for letters and digits, not mathematical operators. That means you can use any ordinary font with this option. And I’ve been using it this way for quite a long time. Only now I’ve discovered this problem with Russian.

Comment: sure, it is no problem to use Libertine for letters or digits, but you are using `\sigma`. Then tell your system from which font it should be used

Comment: OK. How should I do it? The thing is that if I just use english instead of russian and then I do any math magic in between the equation commands (using whatever commands including \sigma or other greek letters), everything works OK and uses Linux Libertine even for those characters represented by commands such as \sigma. That’s the reason why I think that the only problem is the russian setting.

Comment: @Herbert — mathspec can change Latin letters, Greek letters, and digits only (albeit with suboptimal spacing in many cases). So \sigma is okay.