# Shortcuts using double quotes in combination with mathspec

Tags: xetex, mathspec, shorthands

> **Note:** I cannot specificly tell which version of which of the two conflicting packages fixed the issue, but as of 2016 `mathpec` and `polyglossia` no longer show the issue.

Basically, I have encountered the same error as [answered here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28841/using-mathspecs-setallmainfonts-with-russian-in-polyglossia-causes-hang-during) and the workaround suggested by Andrey Vihrov reenables me to compile the document. The problem now is, that any shorthand defined by the ngerman-package (most notably the non-breaking hypen `"~`) has now been disabled, and I see combinations of american style closing quotes followed by a non-break space where a non-breaking hyphen should be.

Is there any way possible of keeping the shorthand definition, or redefining it to something else (something like `\nbhy` pops up to mind)?

I am using XeLaTeX as supplied by TeXLive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work. Basically we are overriding the meaning of the active `"` in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands,spelling=new]{german}

\makeatletter
\begingroup\lccode`~=`"
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \everymath{\let~\eu@active@quote}
  \everydisplay{\let~\eu@active@quote}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
a"~b

\begin{equation}
f(x)=\sigma
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I wouldn't use the `ngerman` package, which is obsolete even for LaTeX.

You can also use `babel`, if you don't have an up-to-date version of Polyglossia.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\makeatletter
\begingroup\lccode`~=`"
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \everymath{\let~\eu@active@quote}
  \everydisplay{\let~\eu@active@quote}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
a"~b

\begin{equation}
f(x)=\sigma
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Something's not working … Changed the ngerman to your polyglossia definition and added the `\makeatletter` stuff, reran xelatex and I still see `" ` i.e. double quotes followed by a space. If I change it to `babelshorthands=false`, same thing. If I now change it to `babelshorthands=true`, I get an error, telling me that a missing { was inserted. Interestingly enough, it was inserted into the line `\begin{document}`, because apparantly XeLaTeX couldn't find it there, and now I am confused.

Edit: Sorry, I hit return, thinking it would make a new line, but it didn't.

Comment: @Jan Please, be more specific.

Comment: see edited version of above comment.  
It's weird that one cannot use simple return to create new lines …

Comment: @Jan No, in comments you have to do Shift+Return. What TeX distribution are you using? I suspect an outdated one. By the way, welcome to TeX.SX! You may try with `ngerman` in place of the Polyglossia related lines, but you'd better upgrade.

Comment: TeXLive as it was supplied to go with Lubuntu …
`This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9995.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)`

Comment: Yes, updating worked (but installing it took three hours >__>). Now with the `babelshorthands=true` I get the non-breaking hyphens back and all errors ommited. Thank you ^___^