# Changing font and using amsmath

Tags: xetex, amsmath, mathspec

I've read several threads about this, but none solves my problem. When I try to change font, it won't compile. Is there an other way to change font, that will still allow me to write stuff like: `$\mu$` ?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article} 
\usepackage[swedish,english]{babel} 
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} %Endast för mac. Om PC, ta bort.
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{appendix}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{csquotes} %Engelsk version.
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{14}{1}\selectfont}
\subsectionfont{\noindent\fontsize{10}{1}\selectfont\normalfont\textit}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.6cm}
\usepackage[MnSymbol]{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts{Times New Roman}
\newcommand{\hs}{\,\hspace{0.8mm}}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{\fontsize{9}{1}\selectfont#1#2#3}
\captionsetup{format=myformat}
\begin{document}
This is a greek letter: $\pi$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.
A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I also suggest to post a MWE (minimal working example): (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: mathspec and commands such as `\setallmainfonts{` that take system font names require lulatex or xelatex not pdflatex or latex (they should give you an error message if you use the wrong engine) are you using xelatex?

Comment: I'm using XeLaTex. I should have specified that.

Comment: @KallePalm OK in that case please edit your question to have a full  document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` and paste the exact error from the log "wont compile" is rather too vague to guess what is happening (my initial guess that you were using pdflatex was wrong:-)

Comment: @KallePalm XeLaTeX requires the file is saved as UTF-8; `inputenc` should not be loaded.

Comment: The only problems I can see are the `\sectionfont` and `\subsectionfont` commands. Where are these defined?

Comment: Error message is: ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros

That is what it says, but it never finishes

Comment: Ian, I missed adding the sectsty in the MWE

Comment: Now your example works without any trouble for me!

Comment: Yeah, me too. I'll change the MWE to a not so minimal WE.

Comment: Now the "M"WE gives the same error as the actual file.

Comment: It's something to do with `\MakeOuterQuote`; the problem disappears if I remove this line.

Comment: Thanks! However, if I remove it I won't get "englishspeaking" style quotes. By this I mean that they hang in different directions.

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\MakeOuterQuote{"}}`.

Comment: No one should use  `applemac` encoding these days, if he/she(/it?) wants a file that's portable on every system. All modern systems understand `UTF8`.

Comment: Ok, I removed the applemac-encoding and added your text @ftbu, but my quote-signs still won't look as I want. Well, I'll have to live with that :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current (2014) LaTeX release your example generates

```
! Package inputenc Error: inputenc is not designed for xetex or luatex.
(inputenc)                only UTF-8 supported.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.165 \endinput

?
```

If I delete the inputenc line and save the file in UTF-8 I get...

nothing, the document hangs (not what I expected:-)

adding `\tracingall` here:

```
 \tracingall$\pi$
```

and stopping it before it filled the disk with log

The basic problem is that `mathspec` makes use of active definition of `"` all over the place and for example  `\pi` is defined as

```
\pi=macro:
->{"π}.
```

I had a quick look at defining `"` to what `mathspec` wants in math mode and `csquotes` wants in text mode, that's probably possible but seems a bit tricky. So not using csquotes active `"` seems a good idea if you want to use `mathspec`

`mathspec` is an old package really and pre-dates most of the development of Unicode math fonts, is there a reason not to use `unicode-math` ?

Comment: `mathspec` uses `"` for adjusting the spacing in mathmode; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62457/4427

Comment: Problem is, if I don't use inputenc, I can't use swedish letters: å, ä, ö. They just become grey boxes.

Comment: @KallePalm No you must be doing something wrong: inputenc _does not work_ with xetex and is not needed xetex is designed to use unicode fonts you can use Swedish, or Chinese or Greek, so long as your file is UTF-8 encoded and you are using suitable fonts (Times Roman should be fine for Swedish) it should all work.

Comment: Weird. I tried commenting out the inputenc-row and all swedish letters become boxes. This might make me look really silly, but maybe I'm not using Xetex? I thought I was.

Comment: @KallePalm do you need to use xetex? (or mathspec?) what features do you need over pdflatex (the most common format still)

Comment: I guess I just started using it as a solution to some other problem long ago. Without mathspec I can't use SetAllMainFonts and thus not change font.

Comment: @KallePalm Ive got to go, and this question has been closed, ask a new question with a new example with some swedish letters in and someone will get you going again